# Storing the value for a random number C

Tags: c, random, numbers, c99

```
//Prompt the user to enter a number
printf("Please enter a number: ");

//Read number
scanf("%d", &number);

//Display number
printf("You entered %d", number);
printf("\n");

//Get a random number and scale to range 3..37
srand(time(NULL));
random_num = (37 - 3) + 1;

//Display random number
printf("Your random number is %d", rand() % random_num + 3);

// Set product to number * random number
product = multiply (number, random_num); //random_num equals 35 ?
```

How can I store the random value generated for random_num to perform the last multiplication?

At the moment the number entered by the user is multiplied by 35. This generates a random number every time, at the end the number is always multiplied by 35.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you set random_num to (37-3) + 1, which is 35.

You can set the random_num = rand() % random_num + 3 to store the random number generated by the rand() function based on the time modulo 38.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new variable to store it:

```
int my_random_number = rand() % random_num + 3;

//Display random number
printf("Your random number is %d", my_random_number);

//Do things with my_random_number
```